# TSC 2307 - Typescript - Cannot find module when deploy on heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a nodejs typescript project that works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy to heroku or send to travis CI it shows me this error.

After running tsc command: **tsc .**

Any help?

**-----> Build
       Running build (yarn)
       yarn run v1.22.4
       $ rm -rf ./dist
       $ tsc -p .
       src/b-controllers/token/token.controller.ts(14,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../d-domain/entities/token' or its corresponding type declarations.
       src/b-controllers/user/user.controller.ts(17,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../d-domain/entities/user' or its corresponding type declarations.**

my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",        
        "module": "commonjs",        
        "moduleResolution": "node",        
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you connect to Dyno and check if the paths the compiler said are correct or not.

Comment: @KyokookHwang I got it! It was a filename bug. Some of them in GitHub was Capitalized like Token.ts... but in my machine it was token.ts... when it was changed, and committed to GitHub the name wasn't changed... idk why... anyway, it works now, thanks for attention.